# Bootstrap 3 not showing hamburger menu and logo on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using the following code to show a logo in the middle and 2 navigation link items on either side. This works perfect when in desktop mode, but when its reduced to mobile, it just disappears. I would like the logo to the left and hamburger menu to the right on mobile. Is this possible?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<header role="banner">
  <nav id="navbar-primary" class="navbar" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-primary-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-primary-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="/advertise">Advertise</a></li>
          <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
          <li>
            <a href="/"><img id="logo-navbar-middle" src="logo.png" width="180" alt="Logo here"></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="/register">Register</a></li>
          <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
</header>
<!-- header role="banner" -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this one**

```css
.mob-Logo {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .desk-Logo {
    display: none;
  }
  .mob-Logo {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<header role="banner">
  <nav id="navbar-primary" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-primary-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a href="/" class="mob-Logo"><img id="logo-navbar-middle" src="logo.png" width="180" alt="Logo here"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-primary-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="/advertise">Advertise</a></li>
          <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="desk-logo">
            <a href="/"><img id="logo-navbar-middle" src="logo.png" width="180" alt="Logo here"></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="/register">Register</a></li>
          <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: In your code when reduce it's not disappeared , it's there. You just have to add `navbar-default` to your nav tag.